# gaussian elimination with openmp

Tags: c, openmp

i am new in openmp and i try to run gaussian elimination method with openmp. but when i increase number of threads (MAXTHREADS) the total time of implementation also increase and that's weird because normally with increasing in number of threads total time should decrease.maybe race condition or over head cause this problem or anything else  but i can,t find that .i would happy if someone told me what is my mistake?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>

#define SIZE 4096
#define MAXTHREADS 4

void read();
void print();
double a[SIZE][SIZE],b[SIZE],x[SIZE],y[SIZE];
int main(){


    int chunk,start,end,i,j,tid,k;
    double start_time,end_time;
    double diff_time;

    read();
    printf("AFTER THE READ FUNCTION \n");
    start_time=omp_get_wtime();
    chunk=SIZE/MAXTHREADS;
    omp_set_num_threads(MAXTHREADS);

#pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,x,y,i,j,chunk)private(k,tid,start,end)
    {

        tid=omp_get_thread_num();
        start=tid*chunk;
        end=start+chunk;
        printf("THREAD %d CREATED WITH START : %d AND END : %d \n",tid,start,end);
        for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++){
            if((k>=start)&&(k<end))
            {
                for(j=k+1;j<SIZE;j++)
                    a[k][j]=a[k][j]/a[k][k];
                x[k]=b[k]/a[k][k];
                a[k][k]=1;
            }
#pragma omp barrier
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,chunk)nowait
            for(i=k+1;i<SIZE;i++)
            {
                for(j=k+1;j<SIZE;j++)
                    a[i][j]=a[i][j]-a[i][k]*a[k][j];
                b[i]=b[i]-a[i][k]*x[k];
                a[i][k]=0;
            }
#pragma omp barrier
        }//k end
    }//end of omp parallel

end_time=omp_get_wtime();

//print();
diff_time=difftime(end_time,start_time);
printf("TOTAL TIME: %1f",diff_time);
return 0;

}

void read()
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                a[i][j]=(double) 10*SIZE;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i][j]=1;
            }
        }

'''
```

Comment: One thing to consider: OpenMP normally uses a number of threads equal to the number of available cores. More than that for computation intensive tasks is usually counter productive. If using hyper threading, half the default number of threads might even be preferable.

Comment: but the problem is that even from one thread to two thread i get increasing in time!!

Comment: If you want an answer, please provide more context. What is the execution time on one thread and how much it increases with as the number of threads goes up? What kind of hardware you run it on and what OS? What kind of compiler? What is the level of optimisation? As it currently stands, your question is basically asking "OpenMP is slow. Why?" And please, be respectful to others here and make your question easier to read by at least using capital letters at the beginning of each sentence. Also, dynamic scheduling with `chunk = SIZE / #threads` is worthless.

Comment: 1) Why are you doing this? (If it;s a learning exercise, OK, I suppose; if not, go read up on BLAS and use a well optimised parallel BLAS). 2) You are timing thread creation, and that is expensive. If you want to measure the performance of your BLAS code have an empty parallel region before starting the timer.